# show this $e^{x_{n}-2n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}-\frac{x_{n}}{2}+n\pi>\frac{1}{5},\forall n\in N^{+}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math

as this:[problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4119198/show-this-x-n1-x-n-ge-2-pi?rq=1),I continue to consider this

let $f(x)=e^x\cos{x}-\sin{x}-1$,and $n$ be postive integer,such  $x_{n}$ be a root of $f(x)=0$ ,and
$\dfrac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi<x_{n}<\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$,show that
$$e^{x_{n}-2n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}-\dfrac{x_{n}}{2}+n\pi>\dfrac{1}{5},\forall n\in N^{+}\tag{1}$$

First we note $e^x\ge 1+x$,so we have
$$e^{x_{n}-2n\pi-\frac{x_{n}}{2}}-\dfrac{x_{n}}{2}+n\pi\ge x_{n}-2n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{x_{n}}{2}+n\pi=\dfrac{x_{n}}{2}-n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
since
$$x_{n}>\dfrac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi\Longrightarrow \dfrac{x_{n}}{2}-n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{2}>-\dfrac{\pi}{3}$$but last no great than $\frac{1}{5}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) = e^{x-\pi/2} - x/2 - 1/5$. We need to show that $g(x) > 0$ for the (unique for each fixed $n$) $x$ s.t. $e^{x+2n\pi} cosx - sinx - 1 = 0$ with $\pi/3 < x < \pi/2$. It's easy to check that $g(\pi/3) < 0, g(\pi/2)>0,$ and $g^\prime(x) > 0, \forall x \in [\pi/3, \pi/2]$. On the other hand, $e^{x+2n\pi} cosx - sinx - 1$ is monotonically decreasing in $[\pi/3, \pi/2]$. It suffices to check the case $n = 1$, we have $g(1.56) > 0$, and $e^{1.56+2\pi} cos(1.56) - sin(1.56) - 1 > 0$, completing the proof.

Comment: hello,you mean $x\in (1.56,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: Basically, $\pi/2 > x_n - 2n\pi \geq x_1 - 2\pi > 1.56, \forall n \geq 1$, and $g(x) > 0$ for $x \in (1.56, \pi / 2)$

Answer (score 0):

In my answer to your previous question, I showed that a good estimate was
$$x_n=2 \pi  n+\frac{\pi }{2}-2 e^{-2 \pi  n-\frac{\pi }{2}}$$ So, the lhs of the expression is
$$e^{-2 e^{-2 \pi  n-\frac{\pi }{2}}}+e^{-2 \pi  n-\frac{\pi }{2}}-\frac{\pi }{4}$$ which is bounded
$$e^{-2 e^{-5 \pi /2}}+e^{-5 \pi /2}-\frac{\pi }{4}\leq \text{lhs} < 1-\frac \pi 4$$ Both bounds are larger than $\frac 15$.